# Installed Gnome Extensions page empty - Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: google-chrome, gnome-shell-extension

I have the chrome-gnome-shell package installed as well as the chrome extension for Gnome Shell, and when I access https://extensions.gnome.org/ I can browse through extensions, install, uninstall, configure, etc., however when I click the Installed extensions link (https://extensions.gnome.org/local/) it takes me to an empty page and can't see my extensions. I've tried this in incognito as well as after clearing cache/cookies and nothing happens.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: **I've confirmed that this problem occurs on two different laptops... so... I suspect that the problem is at extensions.gnome.org... not with our computers. The Tweaks application can still manage local extensions.**

Comment: It's working again :-) The html web source has changed drastically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was at https://extensions.gnome.org.

It's working again this morning. The html web page source code changed dramatically since yesterday.